# db2 how to create a simple update and select Stored Procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

DB2 Stored Procedure update record and select record

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DB2INST1.GETPEOPLE2(IN ids bigint )

    SPECIFIC DB2INST1.GETPEOPLE2

    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1

    MODIFIES SQL DATA

    LANGUAGE SQL 



    BEGIN 

        update test2 set a=a+1 where a>ids;

         DECLARE rs1 CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CLIENT FOR  

        select * from db2inst1.test2;

        OPEN rs1;
END
```

but it's not working.
error: DB21034E The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a valid Command Line Processor command. During SQL processing it returned: SQL0104N An unexpected token "rs1 CURSOR sele" was found following "ids; DECLARE". Expected tokens may include: "". LINE NUMBER=10. SQLSTATE=42601

Comment: Please specify what result you expect and what result you are getting.

Comment: Check the syntax of compound SQL in the manual. All `DECLARE` statements must precede any executable statements.

Comment: DB2 has `SELECT FROM FINAL TABLE` which will return the altered rows (if any) of an inner `UPDATE` or `INSERT` statement. An `INCLUDE` clause can also show the original values before updates.

Answer (score 1):

ok,it work:

```
BEGIN 
        DECLARE rs1 CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CLIENT FOR  
            select * from db2inst1.test2;
        update test2 set a=a+1 where a>ids;
        OPEN rs1;
END
```